# Can I disable markdown parsing in Jekyll entirely?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I recently made a switch to Jekyll, published on my VPS. After giving markdown a try, I still prefer to author posts in HTML which it does just fine.

In my `_config.yml` I previously set `markdown: redcarpet`, but it seems redundant to require this when I author HTML. Is there a way to have Jekyll not pass my HTML posts through a markdown parser, and potentially save rendering time?

Several answers here address enabling/disabling markdown partials, but not disabling markdown entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to disable markdown, just don't name a file as `*.md`, `*.markdown` which will be recognized as a markdown file.

Comment: Originally my files were all saved as `.md`, but I changed them to `.html`. It didn't make any change to the rendering time, so I thought maybe it's still going through a markdown parser.